# ASP.NEt 4 fixing application path

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

In my ASP.NET 4 website most of source paths/references look like ~/Controls/etc..
When I transfer site to server ~/ starts to point to the root of my domain rather then to the folder where site is located hence all those paths become invalid.

How to fix this in one go without fixing references one by one?
is there something in web.config where I can set application path?

Comment: The domain folder should be the root of your application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `~` character is used to base paths from the *application* root, in this case, the root of your domain. What you can do, in IIS, is convert the subfolder to an application (essentially an application within an application), and this will force ASP.NET to use your subfolder as the root of the application.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, is there any way to do it not from IIS, I don't think I have access to this on my remote server.. can I do it from within an application somehow? like in web.config?

Comment: I don't believe you can (someone correct me if I am wrong), but the application base path configuration is derived from IIS, I don't think it is something you can change in code.